# Does the order of the statement in ifelse() matter in R

Tags: r, if-statement

This is my dataset:

```
a <- c(1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1)
b <- c(NA, 1, NA, NA,1, 1, 1,   1,1, NA, NA)
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

I want to create a new variable,that is
when a is 1, b is 1, produce "both"
when a is NA, B is 1, produce "B"
when a is 1, b is NA, produce "A"

I don't understand, why only the last chuck of codes gave me the correct results

```
df$c <- ifelse(df$a ==1 & df$b == 1, "Both",
               ifelse(df$a == 1 & is.na(df$b), "A",
                      ifelse(df$b == 1 & is.na(df$a), "B", NA)))


df$d <- ifelse(df$a ==1 & is.na(df$b), "A",
               ifelse(df$a == 1 & df$b==1, "Both",
                      ifelse(df$b == 1 & is.na(df$a), "B", NA)))



df$e <- ifelse(df$a ==1 & is.na(df$b), "A",
               ifelse(df$b ==1 & is.na(df$a), "B",
                      ifelse(df$b == 1 & df$a == 1, "Both", NA)))
df
```

| a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA | NA | A | A |
| NA | 1 | NA | NA | B |
| 1 | NA | NA | A | A |
| 1 | NA | NA | A | A |
| 1 | 1 | Both | Both | Both |
| NA | 1 | NA | NA | B |
| NA | 1 | NA | NA | B |
| 1 | 1 | Both | Both | Both |
| NA | 1 | NA | NA | B |
| 1 | NA | NA | A | A |
| 1 | NA | NA | A | A |

Comment: I'd consider using `dplyr::case_when` instead of nested `ifelse`.

Comment: I understan ddplyr::case_when is better, but I just wonder why ifesle() would give me different results. I can't understand the logic behind it.

Comment: Since both the columns are containing NAs and You can't use comparison operator to compare NA to something else or even comparing with anything else, when you do this , you will have surprising results. You need to handle this with is.na always. Or use some another functionality

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the order matters. The evaluation from left to right will stop as soon as the result is known.

```
TRUE & NA
#[1] NA

TRUE | NA
#[1] TRUE

FALSE & NA
#[1] FALSE

FALSE | NA
#[1] NA
```

`ifelse` returns `NA` in case the evaluation gives `NA`.

```
ifelse(TRUE, 1, 0)
#[1] 1

ifelse(FALSE, 1, 0)
#[1] 0

ifelse(NA, 1, 0)
#[1] NA
```

So using `ifelse` it could look like:

```
with(df, ifelse(!is.na(a) & a == 1 & !is.na(b) & b == 1, "Both",
         ifelse(!is.na(a) & a == 1 & is.na(b), "A",
         ifelse(!is.na(b) & b == 1 & is.na(a), "B", NA))))
# [1] "A"    "B"    "A"    "A"    "Both" "B"    "B"    "Both" "B"    "A"   
#[11] "A"
```

An alternative could be to use `switch`.

```
sapply(paste(df$a, df$b), switch,
       "1 1" = "Both",
       "1 NA" = "A",
       "NA 1" = "B",
       NA)
#  1 NA   NA 1   1 NA   1 NA    1 1   NA 1   NA 1    1 1   NA 1   1 NA   1 NA 
#   "A"    "B"    "A"    "A" "Both"    "B"    "B" "Both"    "B"    "A"    "A"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `NA` in your `df$a` and `df$b`, you would get `NA` if you do value comparison. Moreover, `NA` is not evaluated in your `ifelse` and would therefore stays `NA`.

For example:

```r
df$a == 1 & df$b == 1
[1]   NA   NA   NA   NA TRUE   NA   NA TRUE   NA   NA   NA
```

Using `dplyr::case_when()` would solve the problem and the code is more readable without nesting a bunch of `ifelse`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df |> mutate(
  c = case_when(a == 1 & b == 1 ~ "Both",
                a == 1 & is.na(b) ~ "A",
                b == 1 & is.na(a) ~ "B",
                TRUE ~ NA_character_)
)

    a  b    c
1   1 NA    A
2  NA  1    B
3   1 NA    A
4   1 NA    A
5   1  1 Both
6  NA  1    B
7  NA  1    B
8   1  1 Both
9  NA  1    B
10  1 NA    A
11  1 NA    A
```